# Is there a way to control which tags get collapsed/self-closed during serialization with MSXML6?

Tags: xml, vb6, msxml, msxml6

I create a MSXML6 DOM document and during serialization I want to control how empty elements are serialized:

1. `<tag></tag>`
2. `<tag/>`

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198419/how-do-i-collapse-empty-xml-tags) describes a solution for C#, but I'm looking for something possible with the ActiveX interface of MSXML. (For VB6 or some scripting language)

Comment: Why you want this, by the way? Both ways are equivalent and are treated equally by any XML parser.

Comment: I have to prepare a document, which is pseudo XML. The processing application chokes on collapsed tags. (And a whole lot of other things, which are perfectly valid XML, but because of some PHB-like decisions are not accepted by that application)

Comment: Since when is VB6 a scripting language?  News to me.

Comment: @Bob: No it isn't, just a grammatical error.

Comment: Seems like the typical issue with XHTML and IE5/6/7 where `<br />` vs `<br/>`  and `<script></script>` vs `<script />` are treated differently. This is usually partially solved with XSLT or post-processing (i.e., run it through a regular expression), do you use XSLT with MSXML currently? Btw, it is *"self closing tags"*, not *"collapsed tags"*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is incredibly messy, but I've discovered that if you use the createElement method on a MSXML document you get (for some reason) an xml element that serailizes to the `<tag />` format, and so you can force elements to serailize like this by replacing them with elements you create with the same name:

```
<!-- Contents of c:\xml.xml -->
<xml>
    <element></element>
</xml>
```

In Javascript (but easy to convert to VbScript hopefully)

```
objXML = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.4.0");
objXML.load("c:\\xml.xml");

var xmlElement = objXML.childNodes[1];

var newElement = objXML.createElement(xmlElement.childNodes[0].tagName);
xmlElement.replaceChild(newElement, xmlElement.childNodes[0]);
```

Conversely, you can force unexpanded `<tag />` elements to expand out by setting the text property to be `""`:

```
newElement.text = "";
```

Hope this helps - I know this is really really horrible, but the chances are the fact that you need to be able to do this in the first place is horrible enough already so this extra horribleness wont make much difference! :-p

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't be hard to create a COM wrapper that exposes to your VB6 app the necessary C# magic capability.

```
using Interop=System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    [Interop.GuidAttribute("...guid here...")]
    [Interop.ComVisible(true)]
    [Interop.ClassInterface(Interop.ClassInterfaceType.AutoDispatch)]
    public partial class MyXmlWrapper 
    {
        // expose methods in here that do the XML serialization the 
        // way you want to.  
    }
}
```

If you haven't done this before, it might seem exotic to define COM objects in C#, but it's not that difficult.