# Converting the Xml tags

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In my xml some of the xml element are empty for example:

```
<A></A>
```

So I want to modify the elements that are of the type shown above to convert to `<A/>` type element so how can we do it in C# and update in the file.

Comment: What is the reason for conversion `<A></A>` to `<A/>`? There is no difference in the syntax from the point of view of any xml parser - so why bother about it?

Comment: while parsing the xml  file in C# the tag <A/> can be identified as IsEmptyElement method but the tag <A></A> cannot be identified by IsEmptyElement method using XmlReader class and in the xml some elements which are empty will represented as  <A/> and some as <A></A>. So to maintain single structure We want to convert empty tags such as <A></A> to </A>.So if any new user is reading they will see the unique structure

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I collapse empty xml tags?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198419/how-do-i-collapse-empty-xml-tags)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I came up with:

```
private static void FormatEmptyNodes(XmlNode rootNode)
{
    foreach (XmlNode childNode in rootNode.ChildNodes)
    {
        FormatEmptyNodes(childNode);

        if(childNode is XmlElement)
        {
            XmlElement element = (XmlElement) childNode;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(element.InnerText)) element.IsEmpty = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(inputFilePath);
FormatEmptyNodes(doc);
doc.Save(outputFilePath);
```

Answer (score 0):

While you [shouldn't use Regex to parse HTML (or XHTML, XML...)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/39709), in your scenario you *could* use it to clean up your incoming strings using the pattern `<([A-Za-z0-9_.]+)></\\1>` and a replacement of `<$1/>`:

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(
  "foo <a></a> bar <a>not empty</a> <tag></tag>",
  "<([A-Za-z0-9_.]+)></\\1>",
  "<$1/>")
```

This will return:

```
foo <a/> bar <a>not empty</a> <tag/>
```

The regex can be understood as illustrated below (image generated by [Regexper](https://regexper.com)):

[image: Regex explained]